# Unable to start service - Requires ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION secure setting

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-location

I got an exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service ...
java.lang.SecurityException: Requires ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION secure setting
```

However I have in `Manifest` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The permission needs to be outside the `<application>` element.

Also, you will need to enable Mock Locations from Settings -> Applications -> Development (Nexus S, may vary on other devices).

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#clearTestProviderEnabled%28java.lang.String%29)